# Code don't read file "*.in" C++, with istream()

Tags: c++, c++14

I'm not familiar with C++, i'm try to read an file example.in, with edges of a digraph, but coping the same code of my class, don't read the file and presents the error discribe below. Both are in the same folder, but still nothing happens. I'm using boost to build the graphs. Thanks for helping.

```
    #include <iostream>                  // for std::cout
    #include <utility>                   // for std::pair
    #include <algorithm>                 // for std::for_each
    #include <array>
    #include <tuple>
    #include <vector>
    #define BOOST_ALLOW_DEPRECATED_HEADERS
    #include <boost/graph/graph_traits.hpp>
    #include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
    
    typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS> Digraph;
    
    Digraph read_digraph (std::istream& in) {
    
        typedef typename boost::graph_traits<Digraph>::vertices_size_type vertices_size_type;
        vertices_size_type num_vertices; in >> num_vertices;
    
        size_t num_arcs; in >> num_arcs;
    
        std::vector<std::pair<int, int> > arcs;
        while (num_arcs--) {
            int u, v; in >> u >> v;
            arcs.push_back(std::make_pair(--u, --v));
        }
    
        return Digraph(arcs.begin(), arcs.end(), num_vertices);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    Digraph digraph = std::move(read_digraph(std::cin));

    typedef boost::graph_traits<Digraph>::vertex_iterator vertex_iter_type;
    vertex_iter_type vertex_it, vertex_end;

    for(std::tie(vertex_it, vertex_end) = boost::vertices(digraph);
        vertex_it != vertex_end; ++vertex_it) {

        std::cout << "Arcs that leave " << *vertex_it + 1 << " go to";

        typename boost::graph_traits<Digraph>::out_edge_iterator out_edge_it, out_edge_end;

        for (std::tie(out_edge_it, out_edge_end) = boost::out_edges(*vertex_it, digraph);
            out_edge_it != out_edge_end; ++out_edge_it) {

            std::cout << " " << boost::target(*out_edge_it, digraph) + 1;
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Error:

```
make
g++ -Wall -pedantic -O2 -std=c++14 -I ~/boost_1_76_0 -MMD -MP -c input.cpp
In file included from /home/marcelo/boost_1_76_0/boost/graph/detail/adjacency_list.hpp:34,
                 from /home/marcelo/boost_1_76_0/boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp:255,
                 from input.cpp:9:
/home/marcelo/boost_1_76_0/boost/graph/detail/adj_list_edge_iterator.hpp: In member function ‘void boost::vec_adj_list_impl<Graph, Config, Base>::copy_impl(const boost::vec_adj_list_impl<Graph, Config, Base>&) [with Graph = boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS>; Config = boost::detail::adj_list_gen<boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS>, boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, boost::no_property, boost::no_property, boost::no_property, boost::listS>::config; Base = boost::directed_graph_helper<boost::detail::adj_list_gen<boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS>, boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, boost::no_property, boost::no_property, boost::no_property, boost::listS>::config>]’:
/home/marcelo/boost_1_76_0/boost/graph/detail/adj_list_edge_iterator.hpp:80:13: warning: ‘*((void*)& ei +48)’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
   80 |             if (edges BOOST_GRAPH_MEMBER first
      |             ^~
In file included from /home/marcelo/boost_1_76_0/boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp:255,
                 from input.cpp:9:
/home/marcelo/boost_1_76_0/boost/graph/detail/adjacency_list.hpp:2186:23: note: ‘*((void*)& ei +48)’ was declared here
 2186 |         edge_iterator ei, ei_end;
      |                       ^~
g++  input.o -o input
./input
```

File example.in

```
5 9
1 2
1 3
2 3
3 1
4 2
4 3
4 5
5 1
5 5
```

Comment: This is a compile-time error, so the program never gets to reading your input file.

Comment: I'm anxious because the professor presented the same code and the file was read.

Comment: If nothing else, the code shown contains 5 opening braces `{` but only 4 closing ones `}`. It can't possibly compile.